# Please help identify this font (possibly from Photoshop Standard Sets)

Tags: font-identification

Can anyone help me with this font? Unfortunately I only have those two screenshots.

I already went through the standard Windows fonts, but found no match.

Furthermore I checked font comparing sites, but did not come across a satisfying solution (either letters or number differed slightly).

I suspect that the screenshot comes from a file that was created with Photoshop, if that is of any help.

Distinct in my opinion are the lower case "a" as well as the slightly tilted "e".

[image]
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite a fuzzy screenshot. Font identifier sites give nothing resembling. Dragging the characters apart and trying to guess, where is the border between black and white changes the situation. Unfortunately the results depends on that guess.

One search result seems a little more plausible than the others:

[image]

One can honestly tell that this is not at all like the original screeshot. Yes, but blur it to the same fuzziness, then it is.

Comment: I am sorry for the poor quality, but I do not have power over that. Your suggested font seems to fit quite neatly, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It may help you, please check offline software here http://fontviewer.net/ - It will show every installed fonts with custom text.

We can check System Default typeface online here, https://wordmark.it/

Comment: I am quite sure that I do not have it installed, I went through all the fonts on the computer.